# JavaScript - Find number of repetitions of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersection, repeat

I have the following arrays:

```
let a = ["egg", "pepper", "salt", "bacon", "beer", "salt", "water", "beer", "egg"]
let b = ["egg", "salt", "beer"]
```

How can I check how many times the words from `b` are contained in `a`?

In the case above the answer will be 2 times, since all the words from b are contained twice. However, if `a` is the following:

```
let a = ["egg", "pepper", "salt", "bacon", "beer", "salt", "water", "beer"]
```

The answer would be 1 since `egg` is contained only once.

Time-efficiency is key here since I will be working with lists with more than 100 000 elements.

Comment: So the output will be 0, if egg is not present in A ?

Comment: @zenwraight Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Use a `Map` with the `b` elements as keys and counts as values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `reduce` method:

```js
let words = ["egg", "pepper", "salt", "bacon", "beer", "salt", "water", "beer", "egg"]

var initialValue = {};

var reducer = function(word, index){
 if(!word[index]){
  word[index] = 1;
 } else{
  word[index] = word[index] + 1;
 }
 return word;
}

var results = words.reduce(reducer, initialValue);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = ["egg", "pepper", "salt", "bacon", "beer", "salt", "water", "beer", "egg"]
let b = ["egg", "salt", "beer"]
let counts ={}

b.forEach(word=>{      
    counts[word] = a.filter(item => item ===word).length
});    

console.log(counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple solution, and the results will list everything in your second list, including zero for the ones that aren't in the data.

The performance should be nearly linear in the sum of the lengths of `a` and `b`. (There is likely some hard-to-measure non-linearity in `a in o`, but I don't know the algorithms used internally to the engines, so I can't be sure.)

Note that the `bs.reduce((o, b) => Object.assign(o, {[b]: 0}), {})` is only called once, to form the initial accumulator for the first `reduce`; it's not a nested reduce.

```js
const counts = (as, bs) => as.reduce(
  (o, a) => Object.assign(o, a in o ? {[a]: o[a] + 1} : {}),
  bs.reduce((o, b) => Object.assign(o, {[b]: 0}), {})
)

const a = ["egg", "pepper", "salt", "bacon", "beer", "salt", "water", "beer", "egg"]
const b = ["egg", "salt", "beer", "tofu"]

console.log(counts(a, b))
```

But the actual performance will likely be less than with some hand-rolled `for` or `while` loops.  `reduce` is simply not as performant as they are.

#### Update

This does not actually answer the question as asked.  I misunderstood the question.  An updated version is

```js
const minMatch = (as, bs) => Math.min(...Object.values(as.reduce(
  (o, a) => Object.assign(o, a in o ? {[a]: o[a] + 1} : {}),
  bs.reduce((o, b) => Object.assign(o, {[b]: 0}), {})
)))

const a = ["egg", "pepper", "salt", "bacon", "beer", "salt", "water", "beer", "egg"]
const b = ["egg", "salt", "beer"]

console.log(minMatch(a, b))
```

Comment: Do note that you're creating a copy of `o` on every iteration of `as` by using spread syntax.

Comment: Yes, another slow-down, certainly.  I'm very much anti-mutation, but one could replace this with <shudder> an `if` statement and a mutation of `o` if desired.

Comment: `Object.assign()` could directly substitute the spread syntax and mutate the existing object without sacrificing much of your brevity.

Comment: You're right, that's probably cleaner.  Updated the answer with this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate array `a` with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Convert array `b` to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and use it as the initial value of the reduce.

If an item from array `a` exists in the Map, increment the value. If not, ignore it. When done, spread the Map's values through [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min):

```js
const a = ["egg", "pepper", "salt", "bacon", "beer", "salt", "water", "beer", "egg"]
const b = ["egg", "salt", "beer"]

const result = Math.min(
  ...a.reduce((m, s) =>
      m.has(s) ? m.set(s, (m.get(s) || 0) + 1) : m
    , new Map(b.map(s => [s, 0]))
  ).values()
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach can be constructing a hash-map while iterating over array A and access that hash-map while iterating over array B (Refer below code)

```js
let a = ["egg", "pepper", "salt", "bacon", "beer", "salt", "water", "beer", "egg"]
let b = ["egg", "salt", "beer"]
let hashMap = {};

for(let element in a){
  if(!hashMap[a[element]])
     hashMap[a[element]] = 0;
  hashMap[a[element]]++;
}

var minVal = a.length;
for(let element in b){
  if(hashMap[b[element]])
     minVal = Math.min(minVal, hashMap[b[element]]);
}
console.log(minVal);
```

Comment: This won't work. `element` will refer to the _indices_ of array `b`, not the _values_.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
let a = ["egg", "pepper", "salt", "bacon", "beer", "salt", "water", "beer", "salt"];
let b = ["egg", "salt"];

const products = a.reduce((result, current) => {
  b.forEach(word => {
    if (word === current) {
      result[word] = result[word] ? result[word] + 1 : 1;
    }
  })
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(products); // { egg: 1, salt: 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a numeric `for` loop to reduce `a` into a plain object:

```js
let a = ["egg", "pepper", "salt", "bacon", "beer", "salt", "water", "beer", "egg"]
let b = ["egg", "salt", "beer"]

const keys = b.reduce((o, k) => Object.assign(o, { [k]: true }), {})
const { length } = a
const values = {}

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  const key = a[i]
  
  if (key in keys) {
    if (key in values) {
      values[key]++
    } else {
      values[key] = 1
    }
  }
}

console.log(values)
```

A numeric `for` loop is faster than `Array` methods like [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and generally faster than `for...of` and `for...in` since it doesn't use [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) or reflection to enumerate the keys of the array.

The `keys` object is to reduce lookup from O(n) to ~O(1) depending on the size of `b`, giving you a total complexity of about *O(n)*. If `b` is also large then use a numeric `for` loop to create `keys` as well, and note that lookup could deteriorate from ~O(1) to O(log(n)) which would give you a total time complexity of *O(n log(n))*.